# Get file status with fs.stat() using inode number, not path

Tags: node.js, linux, inode

Is it possible to get file status with `fs.stat()` (or similar) using `inode` number, not path to file?
In Linux it's possible via `debugfs` eg. `debugfs -R 'stat <2>' /dev/sda2`, but NodeJS seems to use `stat` command.
I have tried to `spawn()` debugfs process and interact with it via NodeJS, but with poor performance results (I need to call such command quite fast)

Comment: Can you give your expectation of `quite fast` ?

Comment: Performance similar to `fs.stat()` would be perfect